# Inputting both Word-level and Char-level embedding in LSTM for PoS tagging

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pos-tagger

I am referring to this research paper "[Learning Character-level Representations for Part-of-Speech Tagging](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/santos14.pdf)", where the author says:  "The proposed neural network uses a convolutional
layer that allows effective feature extraction from
words of any size. At tagging time, the convolutional layer
generates character-level embeddings for each word, even
for the ones that are outside the vocabulary."

I am learning to build an efficient PoS tagger using this approach but I cannot visualize the input format.

for example:

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_dataset()
```

What would an instance of x_train and y_train look like?

I do not understand how do I put word & char embedding (which are dependent on each other) together in a model so that it can learn about them both at the same time.

I plan to put this input dataset in an LSTM model like following:

```
M = Sequential()
M.add(Embedding())
M.add(LSTM())
M.add(Dropout())
M.add(LSTM())
M.add(Dropout())
M.add(TimeDistributed(Dense()))
M.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Can anyone with previous experience in this area can help in sharing some methods or insights to put me on the right track?

I've tried building PoS tagger with hand-crafted features (`total_terms, term, is_first, is_last, is_capitalized, is_all_caps, is_all_lower, prefix-1, prefix-2, prefix-3, suffix-1, suffix-2, suffix-3, prev_word, next_word`) but I want to build a model without them this time.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3145)
I think you must be looking for a model something like the one mentioned on this page.

Comment: doesn't this approach require the input data to be of the same type? Like word-level and char-level embedding will have different type of data representation.